# Fixing Sort Order when Cloning Category Trees

Tags: data-access-layer, shopware6

I am working on a FOSS plugin to clone categories including sub categories in Shopware 6 (as suggested in [NEXT-11360](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-11360)).

It's mostly based on [this code from the German forum](https://forum.shopware.com/t/kategorie-stamm-kopieren-duplizieren/94272/4).

```
async duplicateElement(contextItem) {
        const behavior = {
            cloneChildren: true,
            overwrites: {
                name: `${contextItem.data.name} ${this.$tc('global.default.copy')}`,
                path: null,
                afterCategoryId: null,
                updatedAt: null,
            }
        };

        await this.categoryRepository.clone(contextItem.id, Shopware.Context.api, behavior).then((clone) => {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setIds([clone.id]);
            this.categoryRepository.search(criteria).then((categories) => {
                this.addCategories(categories);
            });
        }).catch(() => {
            this.createNotificationError({
                message: this.$tc('global.notification.unspecifiedSaveErrorMessage'),
            });
        });
    },
```

This works suprisingly well at the first glance.

The current problem is, that the `afterCategoryId` is just copied, then pointing to the source categories and thus sort order is not maintained.
I tried to set this `null` in the overwrites, but this is not working `recursively`. Also I tried to set it to null as a proof of concept in the [VersionManager](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b633651725993d396f3b939c0149ccf8cf6a82b1/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/VersionManager.php#L397)

```
foreach(array_keys($data['children']) as $key) {
    unset($data['children'][$key]['afterCategoryId']);
}
```

but then there is no sort order at all :-)

My next approach would be to subscribe to

`\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityWrittenContainerEvent`

and fix the sort order after the entities have been copied.

I believe there is no suitable even to fix up the data *before* it is persisted?

Or is there an elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

While it is convenient to be able to clone the complete tree with the root, I think it will probably less of a headache to implement your own clone endpoint, if you want to maintain the order of categories within a branch.

Here's a quick, untested implementation of an endpoint:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/api/_admin/my-plugin/clone-category/{categoryId}", name="api.admin.my-plugin.clone-category", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"_routeScope"={"administration"}})
 */
public function cloneCategory(string $categoryId, Request $request, Context $context): JsonResponse
{
    $newId = Uuid::randomHex();
    $cloneBehavior = new CloneBehavior([
        'afterCategoryId' => null,
    ], false);
    $this->categoryRepository->clone($categoryId, $context, $newId, $cloneBehavior);
    $this->cloneChildren($categoryId, $newId, $context);

    return new JsonResponse($newId);
}

private function cloneChildren(string $parentId, string $newParentId, Context $context): void
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('parentId', $parentId));
    /** @var CategoryCollection $collection */
    $collection = $this->categoryRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities();

    if ($collection->count() === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $children = $collection->sortByPosition();

    $previousId = null;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $cloneBehavior = new CloneBehavior([
            'parentId' => $newParentId,
            'afterCategoryId' => $previousId,
        ], false);

        $newId = Uuid::randomHex();
        $this->categoryRepository->clone($child->getId(), $context, $newId, $cloneBehavior);
        $this->cloneChildren($child->getId(), $newId, $context);

        $previousId = $newId;
    }
}
```